# How can I make message bubble?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, chat

Like this:
http://www.premiumpixels.com/freebies/apple-iphone-chat-bubbles-psd/

I have a tcp/ip chat application, I used listbox, but its not the best solution...

Comment: You would have to OwnerDraw the ListBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are programming with the default set of Visual Studio (C#, .NET, winforms) I expect that you also use the defaulted listbox, meaning that that one uses defaulted .

This component can be overridden (even to use customized resources like images, fonts, etc.) It is even documented on MSDN:

[ListBox.DrawItem Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx)

If I were you, I'd look into that example provided there!

Comment: I made a little hack. I've been using a webbrowser in my code, and adding html code to the browser. :D very funny!